# How can I bind two RACChannelTerminals?

Tags: objective-c, macos, binding, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have two NSTextViews that I want synced together. I'm using [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) to generate RACChannelTerminals from their cocoa bindings.

```
RACChannelTerminal *terminal1 = [textView1 rac_channelToBinding:@"attributedString" options:@{ NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption: @(YES) }];
RACChannelTerminal *terminal2 = [textView2 rac_channelToBinding:@"attributedString" options:@{ NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption: @(YES) }];
```

So naturally I thought the next step was just to make a `RACChannel`, then plug in both terminals to it.

```
RACChannel *channel = [RACChannel new];
channel.leadingTerminal = terminal1;
channel.followingTerminal = terminal2;
```

But then the compiler says nope: `Assignment to read only property`. It seems like this should be straight forward, so what am I doing wrong here? How do I create a RACChannel-like binding with my own terminals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two `RACChannelTerminal`s need to be subscribed to each other.

```
[terminal1 subscribe:terminal2];
[terminal2 subscribe:terminal1];
```

The initial value will be ignored, syncing won't happen until new text is entered.

EDIT:

To have them initially synced, I did this:

```
NSString *initialText = textView1.stringValue;

// ... setup channel terminals

[[terminal1 startWith:initialText] subscribe:terminal2];
[[terminal2 startWith:initialText] subscribe:terminal1];
```

Comment: Is there a way to manually force a one-time sync after they're subscribed to each other?

Comment: I updated my answer to show one possible solution for initial sync.